# cwRsync could not resolve hostname

Tags: ssh, rsync

I previously used cwRsync to backup files from WIndows XP to a Linux server

Now I am trying to use cwRsync on a Windows 7 PC (64-bit) to backup to a different Linux server

I installed the free version of cwRsync and set up the environment as in the included cwrsync.cmd except I set CWRSYNCHOME=%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\CWRSYNC as that's where cwRsync installs on 64-bit Windows.

I can ping the Linux server by name and I can resolve it's IP-address using nslookup but when I run rsync I get an error message

```
C> ssh -V
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009

C> rsync -rvz cygdrive/d/Foo xxxx:/home/RGB/Bar
ssh: Could not resolve hostname xxxx: Non-recoverable failure in name resolution
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(610) [sender=  3.0.7]
```

cwRsync includes both ssh and plink in it's bin subdirectory. WHen I run ssh directly I get the same error. However if I run plink directly it connects OK.

- Is there a way to get rsync to use plink?
- Is there a way to get cwRsync's  ssh to resolve hostnames correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If this software respects system-level host information, you could edit the system host file:

- C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\host

It may instead honor your Cygwin host settings:

- **${cygwin_root}**\etc\hosts

Try editing one or both of these files to include the remote host's IP address and name:

`1.2.3.4  hostname`

Be careful not to delete or overwrite any existing name/IP pairs.  Also your anti-virus/malware software (if any) may prevent changes to this file, in which case you may need to authorize the change or temporarily disable the software until after the change.